# Github pat token not working while pushing to repo

Tags: github

We are using github private repo in my organization. we have pat token to repo with this **pat token**  i can able to clone but i can't able to push my changes to github with this **pat** i was below error

git push https://pat:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@github.com/companyname/helloworld.git HEAD:featurebranch -f

remote: You must verify your email address.
remote: See https://github.com/settings/emails.
fatal: unable to access 'https://pat:pat:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@github.com/companyname/helloworld.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: This is a GitHub-specific feature; please don't use irrelevant tags like [tag:git] and [tag:gitlab]. However, the link in your own question *should* answer your question (though I don't know if you'll think it does). GitHub optionally do some extra checking during `git push`, and you've turned that option on.

Answer (score 0):

This message means that you must verify your email address by visiting the link provided and following the steps to verify your email.

GitHub requires this because it's easy to do but relatively effective at preventing spam and abuse, and it also means that if there ends up being a problem (e.g., your account ends up getting compromised or it's associated with excessive use), there's a way to contact you.

This is required in order to continue and even though your PAT is correct, you won't be able to push until your email is verified.

Comment: i already added  my email in github . Do i need to  add the email to pat user in my organization

Comment: It isn't that you haven't added the email, it's that you haven't verified the email as being valid.  As such, GitHub can't trust that you own it.  You have to follow the link and verify your email as directed.